# Searching for a symbolic expression

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that there was a "calculator" that when given a decimal number, it would output the most likely candidate for an exact expression for this number. So, for example, if one were to input $1.414$, the "calculator" may say $\sqrt 2$.

However, I cannot find the "calculator" now. Does anyone know where to find it?

Comment: I've seen several, one that I remember the URL for is https://mrob.com/pub/ries/

Comment: WA, input "[closed form 1.414](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=closed+form+1.414)".